# If I delete game progress from my PlayStation, will it remove it from the ps+ cloud?

Tags: playstation-plus, ps5

I’m trying to delete some things to get some more space for a new game, I noticed that my saved game files take up a fair amount of room. I have saved the one I want to delete from my console to the ps+ cloud, if I were to delete the files from my console, would it also remove them from the cloud?

Comment: I would _think not_.  That would defeat one of the best features of a cloud saving system.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't worry.
Online storage is independent from your local storage, so deleting a savefile does not affect your cloud backup. You need to manually delete files from the online storage. Cloud backup would be useless otherwise.

This also works if you factory reset your console.

Comment: Based on my experience with the PS4, you'd have to manually upload the save to the cloud before deleting it, because the PS4 only synchronizes them sometime between 2 and 5 AM while in Rest mode. Would that still apply to the PS5?

Answer (score 0):

pinckerman is correct and in order to delete a save file you have to go through extra steps. Just to make sure I have listed the ways to delete save files below so you know what would be necessary to delete them.

If you want to make sure to not delete anything by accident you could even save these save files on a USB stick as a backup before deleting the local files.

You can find on the official [PS website](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/support/subscriptions/ps5-ps-plus-cloud-storage/) the mentioned extra steps needed to delete PS5 cloud saves:
[image: Screenshot from PS website for PS5 cloud saves]

In case you are referring to a PS4 the situation is similar even if the steps are slightly different as shown on [this website](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/support/subscriptions/ps4-ps-plus-online-storage/#manage):
[image: Screenshot from PS website for PS4 cloud saves]